# Binding array to multiple DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a scenario where I want to pick 3 items out of a list of checkboxes.  This works fine, but if the list of checkboxes gets long, the page looks  unwieldy. So I wanted to change it to 3 dropdown lists. so the page was a lot smaller, but none of the dropdown lists honor the selected value.

So I tried code like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CheckedLarcenyTypes, new SelectList(Model.LarcenyTypes, "Key", "Value", Model.CheckedLarcenyTypes.Length > 0 ? Model.CheckedLarcenyTypes[0] : null as Int32?), String.Empty, new { id = "Larceny1" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CheckedLarcenyTypes, new SelectList(Model.LarcenyTypes, "Key", "Value", Model.CheckedLarcenyTypes.Length > 1 ? Model.CheckedLarcenyTypes[1] : null as Int32?), String.Empty, new { id = "Larceny2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CheckedLarcenyTypes, new SelectList(Model.LarcenyTypes, "Key", "Value", Model.CheckedLarcenyTypes.Length > 2 ? Model.CheckedLarcenyTypes[2] : null as Int32?), String.Empty, new { id = "Larceny3" })
```

Now the dropdowns are created correctly and the correct value is getting bound and on a POST I see the values getting sent back in the view model.

I just can't get the selectvalue to show in the dropdown.  upon re-loading the page, the dropdowns are still just blank.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is this even possible?

Comment: Hi Fran, if the list is long, why not consider an alternate solution such as implementing a jquery picklist plugin such as one found in http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/ to see whether it would cater your scenario? Unlike a list of check boxes, this will display a dropdown list, from which you can pick up entries. Each entry you select will be listed within the text area

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related to what's described [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx).

> Reading the Selection
>
> If you are using the same model to accept input from the edit view
>   during a postback, you might think the default model binder will
>   repopulate the Albums collection with all the album information and
>   set the selected album. Unfortunately - the web doesn’t work this way
>   and the Albums collection will be empty.

So you must have a ViewModel like this:

```
public class LarcenyViewModel
{
    public int CheckedLarcenyType1 { get; set; }
    public int CheckedLarcenyType2 { get; set; }
    public int CheckedLarcenyType3 { get; set; }             
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> LarcenyTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Populate the ViewModel like this:

```
LarcenyViewModel larcenyViewModel = new LarcenyViewModel();

// Use a database, enum or whatever to get the LarcenyTypes... :)
larcenyViewModel.LarcenyTypes = new SelectList(
               database.FindAllLarcenyTypes(), "LarcenyId", "Name");
```

View code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CheckedLarcenyType1, Model.LarcenyTypes, String.Empty, new { id = "Larceny1" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CheckedLarcenyType2, Model.LarcenyTypes, String.Empty, new { id = "Larceny2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CheckedLarcenyType3, Model.LarcenyTypes, String.Empty, new { id = "Larceny3" })
```

Comment: I've read the post you mentioned and it's actually not the issue I'm seeing.  I don't expect the model binder to bind the entire object.  I simply expected the dropdownlist to work much like any other html object in a post.  If there is a single name for an input object, my understanding is that it will bind the values from all objects of the same name it will bind the values of those items into an array of whatever type that it.  I seem to have left a key piece out which is my view model.  CheckedLarcenyTypes is defined as an Int32[].  this should allow the model binder to bind the values.

Comment: I understand your frustration with this but with `ASP.NET MVC` things don't work this way. I suggest your read this post to understand how to model bind to lists and array types: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: I created a sample app that shows how to databind to an array parameter in the action method. You can take a look here: https://github.com/leniel/AspNetMvcArrayDataBinding

Comment: I found I need to adjust Model.LarcenyTypes to new SelectList(Model.LarcenyTypes, "LarcenyId", "Name") so that I could unset the dropdowns. Otherwise, they all use the same instance of the SelectList and once one is set they all show that value selected.